# Grouping Together CSV Data Using Python

Tags: python, csv, grouping

I have a question regarding how to perform a specific task using python. I feel like this should be pretty straightforward but I’m new to python and I can’t seem to locate a post which specifically addresses what I need to do, which is to group items together from a .csv file. Below I give a description of the csv file that I’m working with and the initial steps that I’m hoping to perform with the data contained in the form using python.

The csv file

The file was generated from a program that I have been using to administer questionnaires. Each ‘column’ has a header; each ‘row’ contains a Participant number and their responses to 100 questions: the questions are in the same order for each participant.

The steps

As mentioned, the data that I need to work with are answers to 100 questions. I need to group the questions into 10 sets of 10 questions each. I need to perform some simple analysis on 5 sets of the ten. After the analysis is complete I need to add 1 of each set of the 5 analyzed to 1 of each set of the 5 that have not been manipulated in any way.

The problem

The problem that I am having is that I cannot figure out a way to group data together from a csv file (such as 10 specific columns from a row) to make up a specific group. I’ve done a little reading and searching on the csv.dictReader_Writer mod/class but I have not come across an example of how to do this as of yet. Has anyone here performed this type of task before and if so, does one go about doing this? Unfortunately, I don’t have any code started as of yet as this would be one of the very first things that I would need to do, besides importing modules of course, in order to manipulate the data in any way.

Comment: You say you don't have code, but it would be very helpful if you could post a snippet of what your csv file looks like (the first 5 lines for example). Also, I'm getting lost when you say "I need to group the questions into 10 sets of 10 questions each". What is your desired output? Do you mean answers instead of questions? Why do you need to group them this way?

Comment: Hi Wilduck-It’s a questionnaire based on 5 traits of personality; n, e, o, c, & a. The questionnaire contains 20 questions for each trait totaling 100 questions. a respondent ranks the questions 1-5 (1= notlikely, 5= extremelylikely). However some of the questions need to be reverse scored, which is why I was planning on creating 10 groups. After these steps are complete the scores of each trait are averaged by the response total within each, eg (n-score)/20. The output Im hoping to generate will be the subject number with each of the subject’s 5 corresponding personality trait scores.

Comment: An example of the csv file with 1 subject (“BFI_1” is not part of the questionnaire_this is only a partial file containing 44 'responses' but is the same format): 

['2015', '1', 'C:\\RUN Behavioral Tasks\\Questionnaires\\BFI_que.exp', 'default.mlp', '8/3/11', '16:05:50', 'C:\\RUN Behavioral Tasks\\Questionnaires\\BFI', 'ok', '5', '2', '5', '1', '5', '4', '5', '2', '5', '4', '5', '1', '5', '2', '5', '5', '5', '1', '2', '5', '2', '5', '2', '5', '5', '5', '1', '5', '2', '5', '2', '5', '5', '4', '2', '5', '2', '4', '3', '5', '1', '5', '2', '5']

Comment: Well, as this question is currently formulated, you've got a lot of moving pieces that a potential answerer would have to take into account. I would suggest taking a few minutes to think carefully about your most immediate problem (csv parsing) and write a minimal example of the problem you're having. Write some sample input, and post it in a new question, write the code you've tried, and the expected result. Basically follow these guidelines: http://sscce.org/ . Also, when you have updates *edit* your question to include the new info, don't post comments.